Assign value to a parameter from custom payload onClick action on Dialogflow CX
Im kinda new with Dialogflow CX and i'm trying to develop a chatbot with custom payload as Agent reponses when a parameter is empty.
At this moment this chat is integrated with google chat for test purposes only. The custom payload (cardsv2) is working fine with google chat.
I have a parameter called "p_segmento" in a page that uses a created entity as entity type with the required box checked.
p_segmento parameter
I added an Agent reponses with custom payload to display a button with the correct value.
Agent response
Here is the full json code:
{
  "cardsV2": [
    {
      "cardId": "seleccionsegmento",
      "card": {
        "sections": [
          {
            "widgets": [
              {
                "buttonList": {
                  "buttons": [
                    {
                      "text": "Cemento",
                      "onClick": {
                        "action": {
                          "function": "$session.params.p_segmento",
                          "parameters": [
                            {
                              "value": "Cemento",
                              "key": "$session.params.p_segmento"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "text": "Indique qué segmento desea consultar, puede seleccionar una opción de la lista o ingrese un texto:"
}

I'm trying to store the selected value from the custom payload into the parameter "p_segmento"  when the user clicks on it, but I can't find the way. It only works when I type the value.
As you can see in the json code, I tried some options in the "onClick" section, adding an action, calling the parameter $session.params.p_segmento as a function and also inside the "parameters" section, but without success.
{
  "text": "Cemento",
  "onClick": {
    "action": {
      "function": "$session.params.p_segmento",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "value": "Cemento",
          "key": "$session.params.p_segmento"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

I believe I need set the correct options inside the "onClick" section, but i'm struggling with that.
Is there a way to do this ? Thanks in advance!
